# C++ DLL returns unexpected array values when called from C# using P/Invoke

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, pinvoke, marshalling

I'm creating a C++ DLL library to be used in a C# application through P/Invoke. The C++ library exposes a function like this:

```
int getData(unsigned char *ptr) {
    ptr = new unsigned char[5];
    ptr[0] = 10;
    ptr[1] = 20;
    ptr[2] = 30;
    ptr[3] = 40;
    ptr[4] = 50;
    return 0;
}
```

where `ptr` is a pointer to an array of length 5. In C#, I have the following code:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    
[DllImport(CppLibPath, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int getData(ref IntPtr ptr);
    
public static void GetData() {
    var size = 5;
    var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
    var arr = new byte[size];
    var result = getData(ref ptr, shouldDetect);
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, size);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
}
```

I expect `arr` to be an array of size 5 containing the values 10, 20, 30, 40, and 50. However, the actual values are different and seem to change every time I run the C# script. Can anyone help me understand why this is happening?

Comment: What is `getIRFrame`? - your C# snippet is not calling `getData` at all.  Also, `getData` doesn't do anything visible to the caller (apart from leak memory).

Comment: I may be wrong, but should it be `unsigned char **ptr` (pointer to the pointer) to allow C++ to change the pointer value and return it. Also, I can't see where you actually call `getData` from C#.

Comment: Is it Windows-only ? if yes, which version?

Comment: The question looks wrong. The C++ function is useless because the array cannot find its way back to the caller. Ask yourself why the arg ptr would be passed by the caller whe. The first action of the function is to assign to ptr. You need to post the real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ptr = new unsigned char[5];` is just wrong: C# has no way of releasing that memory, and it's just overwriting the original pointer. So remove that line from the code in C++. The pointer will already be set by C#.

On the C# side, you can use an array, instead of doing custom marshalling.

```cs
[DllImport(CppLibPath, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int getData
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 5)]
  byte[] ptr
);

public static void GetData()
{
    var arr = new byte[size];
    var result = getData(arr);
}
```

Comment: What is `getIRFrame` and why pass an array when the first line of the C++ allocates an array and overwrites the argument passed.

Comment: Typo I meant `getData`. I mention at the beginning to remove the overwriting of the pointer.

Comment: The thing is, that code in the question suggests that the real code isn't what has been presented in the question. So I rather suspect that the entire question is based on a false premise.